# Display elements inline in a list-group block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am starting with css.
I want to align two icons in column at the right, inside a list-group, i have also a list in that block whose pushing out my icons of the box like this [Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZk4I.png)

```css
.wineItemLine {
 display:block;
}

.list-button {
 float :right;
 display:inline;
}
.wineAttributes {
 display:inline;
}

.list-group {
 max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <body>
  
  <div class="list-group"  ng-controller="listController">
   <div  ng-repeat="vin in wines | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchWine" class="list-group-item">

    <div class=wineAttributes>
     <span class="wineItemLine">
      Un bon vin
     </span>
     <span class="wineItemLine">
      Chateau breton
     </span>
     <div class="wineItemLine">
      <span style="padding-right:10px;">
       Bordeaux
      </span>
      <span>
       Rouge
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="wineItemLine">
      <span style="padding-right:10px;">
       2003
      </span>
      <span>
       3
      </span>

     </div>

    </div>
    <div class=list-button>
     <button class="btn">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></span> 
     </button>

     <button class="btn">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span> 
     </button>
    </div>

   </div>

  </div>
     </body>
```

see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vp3Lapz/5/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code in a snippet directy in the question - links can be broken in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
  .wineItemLine {
    display:block;
}

.list-button {
    float :right;
    display:block;
  width:40%;
}
.wineAttributes {
    display:inline;
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-group {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.list-group-item{
  height: 110px;
}

.btn{
  display: block;
  margin: 7px;
  float: right;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vp3Lapz/14/)